# IIS Application Pool Stopped automatically with Fatal Communication Error when migrated from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2019

Tags: iis-10, application-pool, windows-server-2019

We are facing serious IIS Application Pool issue which stops automatically after regular intervals with below error message as:

**"Application pool 'testapi.com' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool."**

Consecutive Warnings:

***"A process serving application pool 'testapi.com' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was 'xxxx'. The data field contains the error number."***

The issue started happening when we moved our applications from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2019. We cross checked all the IIS/Application Pool settings and its quite similar.

Immediate help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please involve the original developers to fully understand what are the critical settings (especially on user rights and permissions).

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.